# How to count number of rows in SQL table retrieved by a procedure

Tags: mysql

I have a SQL Procedure, let it be Foo(), that retrieves a table.

I want to count the number of rows, and tried both

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ( CALL Foo() );
```

and

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ( CALL Foo() ) ArbitraryTableName;
```

Neither of them works. May I ask for help on this? I am using MySQL.

Comment: `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM .....`

Comment: What Tom said is correct. You can also look at this link for more help
http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_func_count.asp

Comment: Sorry I meant to say COUNT(*)
but still doesn't work

Comment: Dont let it be Foo(), let it be what it actually is so we can fix the actual problem :)

Comment: @user3329564 well the actual problem is that he want to execute stored procedure as a part of his query (into the FROM part) instead of the name of some table... (I think I understand question well)...

Comment: @user3329564 The function name is irrelevant, MySQL complains of a syntax error at the word `CALL`

Comment: I want to check your quoting, variable names, etc. But ok if you want to only show an unfinished question I will give an unfinished answer.